# Display problems with remote connection

Tags: gnome, ssh, vnc, x11-forwarding, vncviewer

I encounter display problems while connecting to my server with x11vnc.

I manage to get a connection and display Gdm but when I login, I get this awfull screen, I suppose it's a problem with Gnome:

[image]

So I wonder:

- Is x11vnc compatible with Gnome?
- Is this a known x11 problem with remote connections?

Here are my configs and commands:

- Client: Windows 10 / VNC Viewer 6.18
- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
- GDM 3.28.2
- GNOME Shell 3.28.3
- `ssh -L5900:localhost:5900 sinsedrix@myservername`
- `x11vnc -ncache 0 -display :0 -auth /run/user/xxx/gdm/Xauthority`

with various parameters (-xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -usepw)